# How to get tableView to be in view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I have a dynamic scroll view, and in that scroll view is a tableView. If there is no data to begin with, the scroll view cuts off before the tableView. The problem is, is that once I load in the data for that tableView, it is out of view. 
How do I "recall" the entire view to load again?

Thank you! If you need any of the code or pictures, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: include any relevant code and or pictures

Comment: Why do you include `UITableView` inside `UIScrollView`? `UITableView` already inherits `UIScrollView` and has all its functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick prototype to show you how to do it. :)

## To add a dynamic UITableView to a UIScrollView:

[image: Add a fixed Vertical Space Constraint to bottom of view]

#### 1. Add a fixed Vertical Space Constraint to bottom of view

Add the UITableView to the UIScrollView and add all necessary constraints, including the bottom constraint (Vertical Space Constraint). This will define a fixed space between the UITableView and its super view (the UIScrollView).

[image: Add IBOutlet to UITableView Height Constraint]

#### 2. Add IBOutlet of the UITableView Height Constraint

From the storyboard, connect the UITableView height constraint to an IBOutlet in your UIViewController class. You'll need this to programatically change the height of the table view.

#### 3. Update the height of the UITableView accordingly

Finally, you can change the constant value of the constrain in code. Therefore, you can make the table view as big or as small as you want. In my implementation (see the image above), in the tableViewNumberOfRowsInSection() function, I calculate how many rows will be in my table view and I also update the height of the table view.

**Some final suggestions:**

1. Why not use a UITableViewController instead of a UIView Controller + UIScrollView + UITableView? The UITableViewController already has an *embedded* scroll view. Any additional views could easily be added as custom UITableViewCells.
2. Another option is to use static cells and create your UI right from the interface builder.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a tableView.reloadData() for refresh the tab and for replace the tab you need to place the code for draw the table into the ViewDidAppear